# Kissing number lower bound vs. upper bound - precise meanings?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, analytic-number-theory, lattices, sphere-packing

According to en.wikipedia.org, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number#Some_known_bounds

It says the kissing numbers $K$ have lower bound $K_L$ and upper bound $K_S$:
$$
K_L < K < K_U.
$$

I am slightly puzzled by what these lower bounds and upper bounds really constrain.

[image]

Here are my puzzles:

1. Isn't that the lower bound can be just 0? The ball does not kiss with its nearest neighbors?
2. Suppose the goal is to achieve the densest sphere packing - then shouldn't the solution always be the highest kissing number $K_U$? What are the exceptions?
3. Are there examples of the lower bound kissing numbers $K_L$ that can give rise to the densest sphere packing?
4. Only when the solutions are found, then the $K_L=K_U$ always? What exactly is the logic here? Why not $K_L \neq K_U$ and $K_L < K < K_U$ at dimensions = 1,2,3,8,24?
5. How about dimension = 4? Why $K_L = K = K_U = 24$?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in the paper "A survey on the kissing numbers" by Peter Boyvalenkov, Stefan Dodunekov, and Oleg R. Musin: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03631

Answer (score 10):

Lots of questions here, I'll see how many I can address. To be clear, $K_L$ and $K_U$ **are summaries of our current knowledge**. There is some true kissing number in each dimension, and hopefully we'll learn what it is someday; this is just what we know now.

(1) The $n$-dimensional kissing number, $K$, is defined to be the maximum number of non-overlapping spheres capable of touching an $S^{n-1}$. So saying that $K_L \leq K$ means that we have found a way to place $K_L$ many non-overlapping spheres so that they touch an $S^{n-1}$. Of course, we could place fewer spheres in contact with a sphere (as you say, we could place $0$), but $K_L$ is the largest number of spheres we have managed to place.

(2) Probably not. The conjectured best packings in $9$ and $10$ dimensions are the $9$ and $10$ dimensional laminated lattices, with kissing numbers $272$ and $336$ (see [here](https://oeis.org/A002336)) and the conjectured best lattice in $12$ dimensions is the [Coxeter-Todd lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Todd_lattice) with kissing number $756$; these are less than the numbers in your table. I see no reason that the densest packing should also have the highest kissing number, but since we have very little understanding of either problem, I don't know if we can rule it out.

(3), (4) and (5): The dimensions $1$, $2$, $8$ and $24$ are very special, because we know exactly what the densest lattice is and it also achieves the maximum kissing number. In dimension $3$, the [Kepler conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture), now proved by Hales, establishes that the optimal density is achieved by the face centered cubic lattice, which indeed has kissing number $12$. I don't know what is going on in dimension $4$.

Again, what is going on here is that there is special structure which allows us to know $K$ exactly in these cases, and so $K_L = K_U$. The other cases where $K_L < K_U$ in the table, reflect our current ignorance, not eternal mathematical truth.